# Count duplicates and copy results

Tags: excel, vba, count, duplicates

I run a performance database and have gotten stuck with a way to track repeat offenders.

In a Results sheet is all the data, I want to create a macro that goes through the results, filters column C to each staff number and count how many times they have a "Fail" result in column D.

If they have a count of 2 or above I want the sheet to copy their name in column B and staff no in column c to the first available line in a different sheet called "Flagged" with the fail count in a 3rd column.

My data runs from rows b8 to b10008 and I have 300 staff who could be assessed

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Wouldn't a pivottable work?

Comment: Possibly but I've ground to a halt on that option too!

Comment: I will try to remember to have alook in the morning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set up your source data as a table (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> with cell in range selected). Add a helper column with the formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--([Fail/Pass]="FAIL"),--([Staff No]=[@[Staff No]]))>=2=SUMPRODUCT(--(D:D="FAIL"),--(C:C=[@[Staff No]]))>=2
```

Create your pivottable, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>,  using compact report layout, and add your helper column to the page field and filter on `True`. Add `name` and `staff No` to the row fields and remove subtotals.

As it is an Excel table you can add more rows and the formula will autofill down. You then just refresh the pivottable to update your flagged list.

**Data:**

[image: Data]

---

**Fields:**

[image: fields]

Compact design layout and no subtotals.

Comment: Hi QHarr, that looks like what I need... can you help me out with a screenshot of your pivot table settings please? They are one of my excel weaknesses and no matter how I play I cant get it looking like yours!

Comment: Added for you now.

Comment: Brilliant thank you, simple but just like cooking rice I can't conquer it.

Comment: Cooking rice is easy! I should put a post about it!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to make use of arrays and loop your data that way, it should be nearly instant (comparing to looping in the sheet itself).

Keep in mind this is not fully tested, but it should get you pretty close to what you are trying to achieve:

```
Sub flagged()

    Dim arrData As Variant, arrFails As Variant
    Dim failCnt As Long, i As Long, j As Long, x As Long, lastRow As Long
    Dim shResults As Worksheet, shFails As Worksheet

    Set shResults = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Results")
    Set shFlagged = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Flagged")

    ReDim arrFails(0 To 300, 0 To 2)

    arrData = shResults.Range("B8:D10008").Value

    For i = LBound(arrData) To UBound(arrData)
        For j = LBound(arrData) To UBound(arrData)
            If arrData(i, 2) = arrData(j, 2) Then
                If arrData(i, 3) = "FAIL" Then
                    failCnt = failCnt + 1
                End If

                If failCnt >= 2 Then
                    arrFails(x, 0) = arrData(i, 1)
                    arrFails(x, 1) = arrData(i, 2)
                    arrFails(x, 2) = failCnt
                    x = x + 1
                End If

            End If
        Next j
        failCnt = 0
    Next i

    For i = LBound(arrFails) To UBound(arrFails)
        If arrFails(i, 0) <> "" Then
            lastRow = shFlagged.Cells(1, j).End(xlDown).Row
            For j = 1 To 3
                shFlagged.Cells(lastRow + 1, j) = arrFails(i, j)
            Next j
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

**EDIT**: changed the size of the dimension to accommodate 3 columns. Also I've initially done this to look for sorted data by staff number, but given is not that much data, that doesn't matter much, so I've edited out the code accordingly.

Comment: Hi DarXyde thank you for your reply. I'm getting a runtime error 9 (Out of range) at line 24. Although I have 300 staff they may not all get assessed during the year. Any ideas?

Comment: That error usually means an array is trying to access an element that hasn't been dimensioned, which was the case here (have a read about [vba arrays](https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-array/) ). Please see the code again, however as said before... this is not tested. It should do the work, but it does require your minimal input changes as well.